# How to get .htm files with links to images to display the images?

Tags: wordpress

I have uploaded an .htm file, which has links to images, and loaded the images, both to the WordPress Media. The .htm file is then added to a page file, and displays only the .htm text and not the image.
The image files show as "un-attached".  Do I need to somehow attach them in order to have them display when the .htm file is displayed?  Or how to I get them to display?

Comment: Show the code please.

Answer (score 0):

apart from it being better to show the code as Samuel Cook says...

Isn't it easier to just past your htm code into the page itself? 
I see no reason why you would do that in an other htm file.

If you can make your situation a little bit more detailed we can help you with more usefull tips